# Line integral along the circle (Correct me)

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Given question :

> Evaluate
>
> $$\oint_C \dfrac{\mathbb dz}{z-2}$$
>
> Around the circle $|z-1|=5$

Since, the center point at $(1,0)$ and has a radius of $5$, i know $z=1+5e^{i\theta}$ with $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.

Then i get

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{5ie^{i\theta}}{5e^{i\theta}-1} \,\mathbb d\theta$$

Then, i'm trying to substitute $u=5e^{i\theta}$

And it gives me :

$$\int_5^5 \frac{\mathbb du}{u-1}$$

(Is there something wrong in my substitution?)

And we know that integral is $0$.

It contradicts with my book's solution which is the answer is $2\pi i$

And actually i agree with my book's solution answer considering i remembered with something formula or theorem like this:

$$\oint_C \frac{f(z_0)}{z-z_0}\,\mathbb dz=2\pi i f(z_0)$$

I just thought about the answer must be involving $2\pi i$

Why? Where is my mistake?

Edit 1 :

> Well, if i really really **can't** do that integration with
> fundamental theorem of calculus bcz the function isn't continuous, how
> do i solve this integration *without* looking too far using
> the residual theorem or the cauchy integral theorem?  let's say I
> don't know yet about those two theorems. I mean i want to solve this using basic parametrization. Without any theorem like green's theorem or something.

I'm too confused, bcz my solution manual said we have to Let $z-2=5e^{i\theta}$, But why? Why we have to do that? We know if we have locus $|z-1|=5$ this means $z=1+5e^{i\theta}$ right? And i know $z-2=5e^{i\theta}$ isn't equivalent with $z=1+5e^{i\theta}$ mathematically.  My solution manual supposing the contour $C$ to be $\Gamma$ which is a circle of radius $5$ with center $z=a,\,a=2$ and letting $z-2=5e^{i\theta}$.

*Does it means, whether we shift it right or left, the contour integral never changes?*

Edit 2 :

Actually i know where is my mistake. What about i'm using long division or partial fraction decomposition like this:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{5ie^{i\theta}}{5e^{i\theta}-1} \,\mathbb d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{i}{5e^{i\theta}-1} \,\mathbb d\theta +\int_0^{2\pi}i\,\mathbb d\theta$$

It will works right? It will gives me the correct answer $2\pi i$

Is it allowed???

Comment: Check when integration by substitute is actually applicable. There are some conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that you are computing an integral like $\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx$. If $g\colon[c,d]\longrightarrow[a,b]$ is differentiable, if $g(c)=a$ and if $g(d)=b$, then we have$$\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_c^df\bigl(g(y)\bigr)g'(y)\,\mathrm dy.$$That's simple and I have stated all assumptions needed about the function $g$. In practice, what we do here is to take $x=g(y)$ and $\mathrm dx=g'(y)\,\mathrm dy$. You seem to believe that this is what you did.

But it isn't. You took an integral of the type $\int_a^bf\bigl(g(x)\bigr)g'(x)\,\mathrm dx$ and you did $x=g^{-1}(y)$ and $\mathrm dx=(g^{-1})'(y)\,\mathrm dy$. But your function $g$ is not a bijection and therefore $g^{-1}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay... suppose i just computing the indefinite integral. Is the answer $\ln{5e^{i\theta}-1}$? What is the "actual" result of the indefinite integral of that, which is when i substitute the upper and lower limit, it gives me $2\pi i$????

Comment: And what does $\ln$ mean in this context?

Comment: Logarithm, cz i have reciprocal (the result that i got). If it's false, then what is the indefinite integral result of that?

Comment: Each non-zero complex number has infinitely many algorithms. Which one are you choosing? Note that no choice will work, because there is *differentiable* function $\ln\colon\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ such that$$(\forall z\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}):\ln'(z)=\frac1z.$$

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway for the answer. I hope i can understand this someday...

Answer (score 1):

The part

> And it gives me$$\int_5^5 \frac{\mathbb du}{u-1}$$

is wrong.

You are actually integrating over the contour where the starting point and the end point meets.

Comment: Before do that, should i just evaluate the indefinite integral of this? The indefinite integral result is $\ln{5e^{i\theta}-1}$ but, what's now? When i'm substituting the lower and upper bound it gives me $0$????

Comment: @user516076  You cannot do that since your contour crosses the branch cut.

Comment: Could you just tell me please what is the result of "indefinite integral" of $$\int \frac{5ie^{i\theta}}{5e^{i\theta}}\mathrm d\theta$$ which when i substitute the upper and lower limit, it will gives me $2\pi i$ Just tell me, without steps is no problem. I'll find out the steps by myself.

Comment: @user516076 Evaluating a contour integral via indefinite integrals "work" if the contour is in a "good" domain. In this case, your logarithm function does not have a "good" domain with respect to your contour. I will have to look up for the exact conditions, but this is anyway the core of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The integral

$$f=5i\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{5-e^{-i\theta}} \,\mathbb d\theta$$

has the value $2 \pi i$.

How can we find this result starting from the indefinte integral, i.e. from an antiderivative?

We have

$$a(\phi)=5i\int \frac{1}{5-e^{-i\theta}} \, d\theta = \log \left(-1+5 e^{i \phi }\right)$$

Applying now blindly the fundamental theorem of calculus the integral $f$ should be the difference of the antiderivative at both of the integration interval.

But, alas, we find $a(\phi=0) = a(\phi = 2 \pi) = 0$

which would give $f=0$.

The problem is that that fundamental theorem holds only if the antiderivative is continuous in the integration interval. But this is not the case here.

As can be seen from the graph

[image]

the imaginary part of the antiderivative has a jump of $2 \pi$ at $\phi = \pi$.

Hence to make $a(\phi)$ continuous we have to add the amount of the jump to the result $0$ which gives an imaginary part $2 \pi$ as stated.

For completeness, the real part is continuous and hence gives no contribution to the integral $f$.

Comment: Actually i know where is my mistake. What about i'm using long division or partial fraction decomposition like this. $$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{5ie^{i\theta}}{5e^{i\theta}-1} \,\mathbb d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{i}{5e^{i\theta}-1} \,\mathbb d\theta +\int_0^{2\pi}i\,\mathbb d\theta$$. It will works right? It will gives me the correct answer $2\pi i$?????